# A LP algorithm in Python to set specific target objective value

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

Given an array of tasks completed along with the qty of each task is there a way to arrive at the likely amount of time consumed in each task if given a total amount of time spent?

For example:

```
series_1_tasks = [[1, 20],[2, 11],[3, 9],[4, 40]]
series_1_total_duration = 16
```

Where [1, 20], 1 = task id and 20 = qty of tasks compelted.

I have several of these series, where some of the tasks are present in a given series and some not.

For example:

```
series_2_tasks = [[1, 16],[5, 31],[3, 9],[8, 3]]
series_2_total_duration = 15
```

I figured I would analyze the distribution of predicted durations for each task to come up with a mean duration over several series. But feel as though there is a more practical way to handle this may be in an ML pipeline with LSTM and backpropagation, but I do not see the path clear enough to achieve that.

I know how I can solve for a single series using Solver in Excel, but how should I structure this problem in python and what tools/libraries should I consider?

Your guidance is appreciated in this problem.

Comment: This looks severly underspecified.I don't see any assumptions / constraints / regularizations and without those, a total duration of 16 mapped to 1 (incomplete <= 20) or to 4 (incomplete <= 40) is equally probably which implies there is nothing to infer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your succinct evaluation. The examples weren't actual any help or even correlate to the actual problem. I realize now I wrote the question before atleast solving it once using solver first. I am sure had I, I've lead with a stronger question. I will do that to help others and hopefully find a suitable answer. My apologies to all who read this before I edit it. :P